# Intermittent Modbus speed

Tags: modbus

I have a Modbus program that configured to poll from a same model of device in several projects. Although I managed to collect all interested data (after some trials), but I found that the data refresh speed could be different significantly  despite the number of data that I acquired are almost the same, ranging from 500 to 510 data. Could I possibly do anything wrong with those slow device?

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: I have voted to close as you have given us very little to work with.  Questions that spring to mind - is it code related or hardware? If it is hardware then that is out the remit of this site.  If it is software, what libraries are you using? What have you tried, why do you think it is this, etc.?

Comment: Well I'm trying to be open as I haven't managed to pinpoint the root cause. However I just found that the communication transaction packet is different from one project to another, surprisingly no error whatsoever from both software and hardware. So the question is narrowing down to how to reduce the transaction in order to speed up the communication? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Modbus program is optimized to poll efficiently.

Through experience, sometimes Modbus polling is slow because the polling method is NOT intelligent and efficient.

For example, if you need to poll from address 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 20. 
Your program should poll 10 to 15 in one go, and poll from 18 and 20 separately.

The essence is polling the consecutive address in one packet instead of polling one address at a time. This will definitely speed up your program significantly if your project is large.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it does help me in some way. After much trials, your info has a little error. The maximum register per transaction can go up to 125, so I should be fetching 10 to 20 in one go in your provided example.

Comment: FYI, here's the link I got the hint: [how to speed up modbus](https://www.integraxor.com/how-to-speed-up-modbus-communication/)